# Python firebase_admin vs. google.cloud packages

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get Firestore working and I am wondering which Python package I should use. It appears that there is some overlap between the functionality of the `firebase_admin.firestore` and `google.cloud.firestore`, as well as between `firebase_admin.credentials` and `google.auth.credentials`. But it also seems like there is some incompatibility between them, or at least they can't be used together.

What is the difference between these Python packages, and which is it recommended that a beginner should use?

Thanks!

Comment: Please let know the documentation referred to arrive at these packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a simple answer for beginners, as requested:

Google provides [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) and [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/gcp) as two different suites of products. Some Google products are [shared](https://firebase.google.com/firebase-and-gcp#:%7E:text=Firebase%20and%20Google%20Cloud%20share%20three%20products) across these, `Cloud Firestore` being one of them.

So, if one is using `Cloud Firestore` from within a [Firebase project](https://firebase.google.com), it is recommended to use `firebase_admin.firestore` and `firebase_admin.credentials` packages and other [Firebase APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python) as required.

If on the other hand, one is using the [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/gcp) project, it is recommended to use `google.cloud.firestore`, and `google.auth.credentials` packages and other [GCP Cloud APIs](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference) as required.

HTH, reach out for any additional questions/queries.

Comment: Thanks! This explanation is more understandable :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use other Firebase functionality (e.g. eventually have mobile users that authenticate with Firebase, and connect to their Firestore instance from their phones or web pages), then [`firebase_admin`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment) is the best choice.

Otherwise, if you plan on using Firestore without Firebase, then [`google.cloud.firestore`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/create-database-server-client-library#initialize) would be more straight-forward.

The same applies to the credentials libraries.

And the main differences are between the Cloud services:

Cloud Firestore supports SDKs for Android, IOS, and Web. Combined with Cloud Firestore security rules and Firebase Auth, the mobile and web SDKs support serverless app architectures where clients connect directly to your Cloud Firestore database. With a serverless architecture, you do not need to maintain an intermediary server between your clients and your Cloud Firestore database.

The Firebase Admin SDKs bundle the Google Cloud client libraries for Cloud Firestore alongside client libraries and SDKs for several other Firebase features. And it is for accessing your Firebase products on a backend server you control, which could be Cloud Functions, or even your desktop. It will typically have full access to everything, as determined by the service account you used to initialize it.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer! Unfortunately I am even more confused now :-) My question was about Python packages, but your answer seems to be about Google's different Cloud services. Perhaps you could edit your post to first describe the difference of the Python packages, and then explain how they relate to the different Cloud services, and what the main differences are between the Cloud services? Thanks!

Comment: @questiondude I have updated my answer, I hope this time it will make you understand clearly.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer! I have read it several times and unfortunately I am still very confused :-) I can see that you work for Google Cloud Platform, so please talk to the project leaders that they need to explain these things much better on their web-site, because it is **very** confusing. Thanks!

Comment: @questiondude Can you just Highlight which part is confusing? So that I can improve my answer.

Comment: I appreciate you want to help and I don't want to be rude. But what you are writing here sounds like a very condensed version of Google's marketing materials. It may make perfect sense to you as an expert, but to an outsider / beginner it's all very confusing. And I actually have a PhD in computer science. So maybe we should just let someone else try and explain it in a way that beginners can better understand. Thanks!